# apache rewrite rule

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, routes

I have problems with apache mod rewrite

I have this code in my .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [QSA,L]
```

to rewrite routes like this

```
sitename.com/index.php?foo/bar/baz
```

to this

```
sitename.com/foo/bar/baz
```

It works fine but I have problems with css|js|jpg|png and all other files
how can I exclude rewriting rules for specific types of files?

Answer (score 0):

You just need an additional [rewrite condition](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) which tests for that kind of filename:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/\.(css|js|jpg|png)$/i
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [QSA,L]
```